# Conditional formatting VBA scripting (not IN excel)

Tags: vba, scripting, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been developing a script that runs through a Txtfile, retrieves certain references, stores these refs in a variable in the form of `('ref1','ref2','ref3',...)` so that after retrieving these refs I can query our database to retrieve 10 columns from the database.

I add this result to an Excel file, like this:

```
If rs.BOF = False Or rs.EOF = False Then
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.workbooks.Add()
    Set baseSheet = objWorkbook.worksheets(1)

    fldcount = rs.Fields.count
    For icol = 0 To fldcount - 1
        baseSheet.Cells(1, icol + 1).VALUE = rs.Fields(icol).Name
    Next
    baseSheet.Range(baseSheet.Cells(1, 1), baseSheet.Cells(1, rs.Fields.count)).Font.Bold = True
    baseSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    objExcel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
    objExcel.Columns("A:J").Select
    objExcel.selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    baseSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    objExcel.Visible = True
Else
    MsgBox ("Geen speciale gevallen")
    Exit Function
End If
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set baseSheet = Nothing
```

My question : **Can I run through objExcel column "J" and test for a value (`if instr(contents of column "J", "400 - 700") > 0 Then` backgroundcolor for that cell = yellow)**?

I can't disclose the other parts of the code since they are lengthy and might reveal where I work etc.

To be clear this is not in Excel, it is in an attachmate reflection IBM terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help you :

```
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "J"), "400 - 700") <= 0 Then
        Else
            .Cells(i, "J").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            .Cells(i, "J").Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Cells(i, "J").Interior.Color = 65535
        End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion! Do I add this right after comyfromrecordset rs command?

Comment: Also, should I address activesheet with objExcel.activesheet or objWorkbook.activesheet?

Comment: `objWorkbook.activesheet` or `objWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName_As_String")` for references. And yes place it after `baseSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs`. Btw is it normal that you copy it twice?

Comment: And change `objExcel.Columns("A:J").Select
    objExcel.selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit` to `objWorkBook.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit` it'll be more efficient as the `.Select` is really ressources-greedy

Comment: Thanks! Last problem: For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).ROW -> The xlUp variable is not defined, can I just declare this or is there another way of addressing this?

Comment: objWorkBook.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit gives runtime error '438': Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: My bad, I forgot the **sheet reference** in the middle : `Application.Workbook.Sheet.Range` . For `Const xlUp = -4162 (&HFFFFEFBE)`, you can try the numerical values. I think that you haven't a constant numbers of rows, so you still need something to calculate your last row for the loop, maybe with `fldcount` can be reuse?

Comment: the problem now is that the xlSolid and xlAutomatic aren't defined, + I suddenly get a 'end with without with' error

Comment: Hi, conditional formatting works! Thanks a lot! Last, and I mean last question, can you write out the right line for "objWorkBook.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit" please? Last thing that doesn't work, everything else is working awesomely! Thanks again.

Comment: Change it to "objWorkBook.Sheets(" SheetName-As-String").Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit" and replace SheetName-As-String by the name of your sheet (probably Sheet1)

Comment: Hi, I get a 'type mismatch' error, run-time error '13', sheet1 can't be used but I used 'basesheet' since I declared that as 'Set baseSheet = objWorkbook.worksheets(1)', is this wrong reasoning? Or should I just declare sheet1 and use that? Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Comment: If I use "objWorkbook.Sheets("basesheet").Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit" I get the error 'subscript out of range'

Comment: IT WORKS thank you so much, I had to put sheet1 between parenthesis, thanks for  your help

Comment: My bad, I forgot that you had define `BaseSheet`, and as it is an object (so with included references) you can use it like this : `BaseSheet.Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit`. The solution with parenthesis uses an index (integer) or the name of the object (string). Glad I could help! ;)